# Run command line using setup factory

Tags: powershell, installation

I have script of powershell that create ftp site [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522557/set-permissions-and-settings-on-iis-ftp-site-using-powershell) 
how I can run this script in on-startup using setup factory program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on-startup(before setup begin)

runscript("NameOfYourPowerShell.ps1");

---

```
function runscript(path)
l1="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe C:\\"
l2=path
    file = io.open("c:\\runscript.bat","w");
    file:write(l1..l2);
    file:close("c:\\runscript.bat");
    Shell.Execute("c:\\runscript.bat", "", "", "", SW_HIDE,true);
    File.Delete("c:\\runscript.bat");
end
```